# Simple way to write sync functions in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, tdd

For testing purposes my code would look nicer if I would be able to execute some test functions waiting in sync for their results.

I know the principal ideas about event programming in node.js, but during tests which are run synchronously blocking processor is not a problem for me.

Is there any simple (one-liner would be best) solution to execute function which returns some values by  callback(err, ret)  to return that ret by "return", and pretend that execution is synchronous.

Comment: This is one question with node.js that I am forever seeking. Like you, I just want to make a function synchronous, and return like it's synchronous. Hope someone can give a better answer than using async, fibrous, etc, which still don't make that function return the value!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no better solution for that. Promise pattern might be solution in some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use node-sync for that purpose https://github.com/0ctave/node-sync

But in general I'd recommend you don't. The mocha test framework for example allows you to do async tests. Also async waterfall https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall is a nice way to pseudo synchronize your code.

I'd say stay in the async mind frame. Even when testing.

Comment: Sure, I don't recommend anyone to use that. In my specific cases for mocha tests simply that would be better.

Comment: Sure I know that. My question is more for code organization. If I need to prepare for instance several random parameters before execution my code looks like a mess.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha has built-in `done` callback function to make this happen. The pattern I use for my code:

```
describe('some spec', function () {
   beforeEach(function (done) {
      // common spec initalization code..
      common.init (function (err, stuff) {
         done(err);
      });
   });

   describe('particular case', function () {
      var result, another;

      beforeEach(function (done) {
         // case init 1..
         case.init(function (err, res) {
            result = res;
            done(err);
         }); 
      });

      beforeEach(function (done) {
         // case init 2..
         case.init2(function (err, res) {
            another = res;
            done(err);
         }); 
      });

     it ('should be smth', function () {
       expect(result).to.equal(0);
     });

     it ('should be smth else', function () {
       expect(another).to.equal(1);
     });

   });
});
```

Comment: I know that. My question was about diffrent thing.